# How to iterate list and group by word frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to find the number of times a word appears in a list from a csv file.
I've tried:

```
df['Size'] = df['Interests'].str.extract('([\S]*[\w])')
sizes = df.groupby('Size').size()
```

Where Interests is the column I'm analyzing. However, that code does not work. Instead it only prints the first word of each row. So for instance, if my Interests column contains the following entries:

```
Apple, Banana, Pear, Peach
Banana, Orange
Strawberry, Apple, Banana
Mango, Pear, Orange
```

Then my Sizes column will contain the following:

```
Apple        1
Banana       1
Strawberry   1
Mango        1
```

Instead of

```
Apple        2
Banana       3
Strawberry   1
Mango        1
Pear         2
Peach        1
Orange       2
```

How can I fix this? I've tried putting it in a loop, but I get errors. For instance, if I do:

```
for i in df['Interests']:
      df['Size'] = i.str.extract('([\S]*[\w])')
sizes = df.groupby('Size').size()
```

I get the error 'float' object has no attribute 'str'.

I've also tried: `for i in range(df['Interests']):`

But get: TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post images of your data, post the actual data and format it as code.

Comment: sorry about that, I fixed it.

Comment: I realized after posting an answer that I don't know Pandas (that's what you're using, a Pandas DataFrame, right?) well enough to know quite how to do this.  I see how `extract('([\S]*[\w])')` is getting just the beginning of the column's value, giving you just the first word.  What I was attempting to do in my code was split that up into multiple values, which I did.  But I don't know what to do with the multiple values.  I can't just assign them all to df['Size], right?  That code must be in the context of a single row in your table, so I don't know how to have it address multiple rows.

Comment: That's ok, I still really appreciate you trying to help. Yes, I am using Pandas dataframe. I'm in the same boat as you as I'm still a bit new to using pandas

Comment: I dont understand your expected output, do you only want the count fr the first item?

Comment: I want to count for all the items. But each row contains more than one item. I want all the items in each row to be accounted for

Comment: but then your expected output example is wrong because it shows only the first item count per row

Comment: @shorttriptomars - Can you please post how your dataframe looks? Is each entry in the column another list which is `['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Peach']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the basic pandas methods are going to be enough for this problem, since it seems like you want to count words within entries rather than simply counting entries matching some criteria. You'll probably need to write something that iterates through entries and then words within entries. Accumulating the results in a dictionary seems sensible to me. Here's an example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
for entry in df['Interests'].values:
    for word in entry.split(','):
        # Perform any massaging required here, e.g. such as if you want to be case-insensitive
        counts[word] += 1

# counts now maps words in the entire column to number of counts of those words
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use collections Counter, which gives you a dictionary with frequencies of items in a list. Since you have a a string representation of the list of words in each row, first split the text into those lists.

```
from collections import Counter
df['Size'] = df['Interests'].str.split(", ").map(lambda x: Counter(x))
print(df['Size'])
```